# Excluding projects from build for certain configurations in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a few different solution configurations in my VS2010 solution. For some of those I only want to build a subset of the included projects. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz.aspx) should do the trick for you.

Comment: So it does. Totally missed the checkbox... :s